# Save sensible information on Android

Tags: android, security, android-sharedpreferences

I'd like to store sensible information for the user like email and token. What do you recommend me to do? Using shared preferences maybe? Using something like https://github.com/scottyab/secure-preferences?

Answer (score 0):

use shared preference as it is easy to store and also easy to access. you should not consider to use sqlite as it is bit complicated and also lengthy method.